# multiple facebook like buttons in a website

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have integrated the Like button for the website,but for some pages i need recommed / like for the individual items. Both are on same page similar to product detail & site.

I have integrated but the url posting on facebook for the product details is same as the website. I want the url to be that of the product for the product like  & Site URL for the Site like.

I have kept all the opengraph tags as stated in fb.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the href attribute (cf:http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Comment: Yes i have made different hrefs for the buttons but when i clicked like The URL posted on FB is wrong. Please Help.

Comment: then your og meta tags are wrong for the URLs you're linking to, or else you're redirecting back to the main page, something like that

Comment: How to dynamically link the urls for example: my website url is "mysite.com/default.aspx" & my product detail is "mysite.com/myproductdetils.aspx/id" my og:url is to the "mysite.com/default.aspx" but when i click on site like i need this url to be posted & when i like my product  "mysite.com/myproductdetils.aspx/id" must be posted how to change the url posting dynamially/ any other tag which i can use to post it correctly please help